# Can I treat CryptoStream as a replacement for SslStream?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, security, ssl

I need to send data between SilverLight applications. I've got requirement that says that data should be transmitted using secure protocol such as SSL/TLS. Data is sent using TCP sockets due to performance reasons. Unfortunately SilverLight doesn't support [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx). If I want to transmit data over SSL/TLS I need to buy third party library e.g. [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/). I don't want to be dependent on third party libraries when it comes to handling transport layer.

However, SilverLight has [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) class. I'm thinking of exchanging the key for symmetric encryption using WCF over SSL (SilverLight supports that) and then encrypt the data with AES using CryptoStream.

Is this solution safe? Can it be compared to using SSL/TLS in terms of security? Is there some obvious security hole that I'm missing?

Comment: SSL provides not just encryption, but a bunch of other things like packet integrity checking, authenticated encryption, secure key generation, proper encryption modes etc., compression and so on.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I'm in full control of both parties that exchange information. The keys are exchanged using SSL and I know that both parties are able to use AES. I guess there is no way anyone could decrypt the data without knowing the key. I agree that someone would be able to interrupt the transmission but it will be only noise since he would have to know the key to encrypt data with it. Do you see any flaws in terms of security of the message (by it I mean that someone who is unathorized sends his data as part of transmission or reads data from my transmission)?

Comment: Reliable encryption mode for AES should be chosen, and you need to negotiate both the key and IV. But if you can connect using WCF over SSL, is there a reason to not use WCF for further communication?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I will be sending live video data and WCF gives too much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main problems with the AES approach is key management and key verification.  I'm sure you know that SSL uses a 'handshake', which uses a CA chain (Certificate Authority) to verify the validity of the SSL certificate.  This all happens before an AES key is generated for the SSL session.  So, by not using SSL, you miss this important step.

This means that you take on the responsibility for verifying that the keys are secure and exchanged in a secure manner.

Comment: If SSL/TLS connection is used to exchange session keys, then there should be no validation problem.

Comment: Keys are exchanged in a secure manner - I will be using webservice call over https.